# Finding same value index of pandas Series

Tags: pandas

Assume below pandas Series having same value index B, C.

```
from pandas import Series

s1 = Series({'A':90, 'B': 95, 'C':85})
s2 = Series({'C':85, 'D':50, 'B': 95})
```

To find same value index, I did below but it fails.

```
>>> s1==s2
A    False
B    False
C    False
dtype: bool
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this script, you'll be dropped into the pdb debugger right before `s1 == s2`:

```
import pandas as pd
s1 = pd.Series({'A':90, 'B': 95, 'C':85})
s2 = pd.Series({'C':85, 'D':50, 'B': 95})

import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
s1 == s2
```

If you step through [the code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/ops.py#L700) you'll quickly arrive at

```
    if isinstance(other, pd.Series):
        name = _maybe_match_name(self, other)
        if len(self) != len(other):
            raise ValueError('Series lengths must match to compare')
        return self._constructor(na_op(self.values, other.values),
                                 index=self.index, name=name)
```

Notice that `na_op`, the function which does the equality comparison, takes `self.values` and `other.values`. `self` is `s1` and `other` is `s2`. The `.values` attribute return NumPy arrays:

```
In [49]: s1.values
Out[49]: array([90, 95, 85])

In [50]: s2.values
Out[50]: array([95, 85, 50])
```

So by definition, the way Pandas performs equality comparison of two Series *ignores the index*.

If you want to perform a numeric equality check which aligns values based on the index, you could use

```
In [48]: s1-s2 == 0
Out[48]: 
A    False
B     True
C     True
D    False
dtype: bool
```

---

More generally, if the values are not numeric, you could use `pd.concat` to concatenate the Series into a DataFrame. This aligns the two Series based on the index:

```
s1 = pd.Series({'A':'foo', 'B': 'bar', 'C':'baz'})
s2 = pd.Series({'C':'baz', 'D':'quux', 'B': 'bar'})
df = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)
#      0     1
# A  foo   NaN
# B  bar   bar
# C  baz   baz
# D  NaN  quux
```

Once the indexes are aligned, you can compare values with `==`:

```
In [20]: df[0] == df[1]
Out[20]: 
A    False
B     True
C     True
D    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: What if values are not numeric but still want to find same valued indice?